# Scale Y_train in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I know that in NN before creating model we should make `X_train` data between 0 and 1. 
But what about `Y_train` in regression NN? Should we keep original values or scale it too?

Comment: What values need to be taken by `Y_train` depends on your loss function. For a conventional two class classification problem, the label space could be either `{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {10, 01}`. For example, for categorical cross-entropy, a one-hot encoded label space is preferred like the last one.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar and for regression problem?

Comment: That is a different issue. You should scale carefully as it could change how the model is being learned. Lets say you scale by log, then you will reduce the effects of outliers but at the same time worsen the predictions too.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar thank you!

Comment: @Perfavore you should transform BoxCox so that Y_train will have a normal distribution